# Google Play Reviews with Python

Tags: python, api, google-play

Good afternoon
This is my first time trying to connect to Google Play reviews using Python*
I do have my api key.
I am unsure where to begin or the first steps needed to make the connection.
I have searched Google to find a starting point. https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews
I have installed the Google Play python packages.
If anyone could explain or show me how to make the connection to Google Play Reviews, I can figure the rest out.

Comment: use https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil to get data in python

Comment: use https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil to get data in python

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question? Would you please share your code as an answer to the post?